# NOT able to record sound in android?

Tags: android

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button mStart;
Button mStop;
Button mPlay;
Button mPlayStop;

 private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
  private static String mFileName = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.strt);
    mStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    mStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stp);
    mStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    mPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ply);
    mPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    mPlayStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.plystp);
    mPlayStop.setOnClickListener(this);
     mFileName = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest1111";




}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.strt:start();

                    break;
    case R.id.stp: stop();
                    break;
    case R.id.ply: play();
                break;
    case R.id.plystp:playstop();
                break;

    }
}

public void start(){
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    recorder.start();


}
public void stop()
{
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;

}
public void play()
{
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }


}
public void playstop()
{
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;

}


}
```

LOGCAT

```
02-25 11:32:18.383: E/MediaRecorder(12854): start failed: -2147483648
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at com.example.recorder.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.java:93)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at com.example.recorder.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-25 11:32:18.403: E/AndroidRuntime(12854):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ideas for you to try:

1. Try adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
   ```
2. If you're running your code on emulator, don't, as it's not supposed to work [(docs here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#start%28%29)

If you're counting on more help, I'd also suggest improving your question and adding more info regarding your setup.

---

**Edit: here's a complete, working solution**

Several things were broken in your code:

1. You were using new instances of MediaRecoder in every start()/stop() call. You cannot do that, those are stateful objects. When you start recording/playback using one object, you cannot nullify it, instantiate again and call stop().
2. You were writing audio file to app's cache directory. As it turns out, it's broken - fix is to use SD card for storing files. It requires additional permission:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

Here's the code. I've deleted some parts to keep it a little bit shorter - you'll have to fill in those places:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    /* TODO: Initialize buttons & other stuff here */ 

    private static String mFileName = null;

    /* NOTE: using one instance of player and recorder. */
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* TODO: Buttons code here */

        /* NOTE: Writing to SD card, not app cache */
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest1111";
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* TODO: your old code here */
    }

    public void start() {
        /* NOTE: Use class variable, not local one. */
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        /* NOTE: Use class variable, not local one. */
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        /* NOTE: Use class variable, not local one. */
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    public void playstop()
    {
        /* NOTE: Use class variable, not local one. */
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: these are already added in manifest

Comment: And you're running it on a device, right?

Comment: tried on both device and emulator

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer with complete, working example. Hope it helps.